# How to match and categories mysql data in the background?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I was researching about this but couldn't find any tutorial as I don't know what exactly the program is used in this matter.

I have mysql data of expenses. 
What I want is after user add new expense, it automatically categories that transaction based on the supplier name or the description provided.

For example if the transaction is:
Supplier/Store: Mc Donalds
Date: 15/06/2016
Amt: $10.00
Tax: $1.00

Then column "Category" should automatically be filled by "Food" may be sometime later in the background.

Hope you can give me a kick start.

Thanks

Comment: What you're seeking is a [Relational Database](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/question599.htm). *How* to edit/update fields is a different matter.

Answer (score 0):

if I am clear to your question. I think you should use a session.
if the user add expense, then you automatically push that expense to the multidimensional session.

you just put the session in a html tag that always update every seconds (use settimeout or setinterval in javascript )

because what im trying to say here, is that its easy to call function or data when it is inside the session. and if the user is done the process. thats the time you will save all changes into database. just like a shopping cart.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about a very difficult problem to solve completely.

You can have a trivial solution by mapping a list of known supplier names to categories, but that won't be too useful with real life data, where supplier names can vary a lot according to user input, not to mention the amount of effort required to maintain that list.

If you want to start parsing descriptions for categories, it's even harder, involving NLP and probably some sort of machine learning algorithm from user feedback.

TLDR; Entire teams of Masters/PhDs are usually tasked with what you want to achieve, good luck. It's also not an exact science, but an art, so no exact algorithm exists, at least not in the public domain.

Comment: Hi populus, I don't think it's that hard what you believe. Alot of personal finance websites use this kind of trick which categorize the bank transactions to their expected category based on the description in the transaction and also they learn if you manually change the category so they categorize it correctly in the future.

Comment: Yes, banks, where they have a team to handle it. They also have access to more information that what is display in receipts, i.e. merchant details from merchant id, localized data for merchants with same names but different location...etc. If you can get your hands on that data, it makes your life much easier. But if you have none of that, you have to make sense of the transaction data, since they're all just strings to a computer, and since you don't have all the data to connect the dots, you have to use a learning algorithm.

Comment: You can get your hands on all the data I mentioned, but it requires $$$$, and being security certified across all your systems, which is more $$$$. And yea, a team to coordinate all that data, and a lot of time. Please do not underestimate what you are trying to achieve.